ASP.NET Core Web API : convert json payload to one format
Some of the properties in the JSON are in camel case, while others are in snake case, such as re_broadcast_timestamp and corporate_actions. As a result, it's not binding the model correctly and throwing an error.
Here's an example of the JSON payload:
{
    "announcements": {
        "data": [
            {
                "symbol": "",
                "broadcastdate": "20-Jul-2024 10:02:19",
                "subject": "Ans"
            }
        ]
    },
    "corporate_actions": {
        "reDilEPS": "16.68",
        "reProLossBefTax": "1505100",
        "proLossAftTax": "1128300",
        "re_broadcast_timestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",
        "xbrl_attachment": "https://"
    }
}

I have declared the C# properties as follows:
public decimal ProLossAftTax { get; set; }
public string? ReBroadcastTimestamp { get; set; }
public string? XbrlAttachment { get; set; }
public string? NaAttachment { get; set; }

Note: I have N number properties in the JSON, manual binding is difficult using System.Text.Json.Serialization.
public class CorporateActions
{
    [JsonPropertyName("reDilEPS")]
    public string? ReDilEps { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("reProLossBefTax")]
    public string? ReProLossBefTax { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("proLossAftTax")]
    public decimal ProLossAftTax { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("re_broadcast_timestamp")]
    public string? ReBroadcastTimestamp { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("xbrl_attachment")]
    public string? XbrlAttachment { get; set; }
}

public class AnnouncementData
{
    [JsonPropertyName("symbol")]
    public string? Symbol { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("broadcastdate")]
    public string? BroadcastDate { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("subject")]
    public string? Subject { get; set; }
}

I tried adding the following code in the Startup file:
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});

And here is the excepted JSON result I need to serialize and pass to controller (without under_score) or if it's any of the other format before sending to controller it should be translated to one correct format.
"announcements": {
    "data": 
        [
            {
                "symbol": "RELIANCE",
                "broadcastdate": "20-Jul-2024 10:02:19",
                "subject": "Anates"
            }
        ]
},
"corporateactions": {
    "redilEPS": "16.68",
    "reproLossBefTax": "1505100",
    "proLossAftTax": "1128300",
    "rebroadcasttimestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",
    "xbrlattachment": "https://"
}]


To solve the issue, creating a custom JsonNamingPolicy that can handle both Camel Case and Snake Case properties JsonNamingPolicy
public class SnakeCaseNamingPolicy : JsonNamingPolicy
{
    public override string ConvertName(string name)
    {
        return string.Join("", name.Split('_')
            .Select((word, index) =>
            index == 0 ? word : char.ToUpperInvariant(word[0]) + word.Substring(1)));
    }
}

In your startup.cs or program.cs
builder.Services.AddControllers().AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = new SnakeCaseNamingPolicy();
    options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy = JsonNamingPolicy.CamelCase;
});


If user passes payload like this in json
{ "re_broadcast_timestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",         "xbrl_attachment": "https://" }
it has to convert like this and pass to controller in the following way
{ "reBroadcasTtimestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",         "xbrlAttachment": "https://" }

If n number of users pass a payload in any format, like this in JSON:
{   "re_broadcast_timestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",   "xbrl_attachment": "https://" } 
It has to be converted and passed to the controller in the following format:
{   "reBroadcastTimestamp": "22-Apr-2024 19:40",   "xbrlAttachment": "https://" } 

public class FinancialResult     { public string? ReBroadcastTimestamp { get; set; }        public string? XbrlAttachment { get; set; } }
Here is my property names
